# Protractor and Saucelabs send testname

Tags: protractor, saucelabs, browser-testing

I successfully have my Protractor tests running on SauceLabs, Although I would like to be able to send the names of my tests up to the service, for example all my tests are being grouped by browser name.

Is there a way I can pass the test names up to SauceLabs?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using Selenium for Python. However, I understand that with Protractor, you'd edit your `conf.js` file so that the `capabilities` option would be contain a `name` field with the name of your test. I also suggest using the `build` field to know what build of your code you are using:

```
capabilities: {
    name: 'whatever name',
    build: 'whatever build',
    // Anything else you need
}
```

The [`name`](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/test-configuration/#recording-test-names) and [`build`](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/test-configuration/#recording-test-names) fields are cross platform.

Comment: I have seen the name and build fields, but the issue is these get set before the code starts running, so I can't pass the test name into the. I can get the name of each test by running a ```this.description``` on the ```beforeEach``` but I am struggling to inject that into the config.

Comment: `name` and `build` can only be set when a Selenium instance is started. How many instances do you start in your test suite?

Answer (score 0):

If, during your test, you have the SauceLabs  sessionId, then its as simple as sending a JSON packet to [the REST API](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/rest-api/).

```
curl https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/users/USERNAME -u YOUR_USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY
```

You can probably test this by starting a manual SauceLabs session, getting the session ID from it, and then manually sending the API request in a browsser JSON REST client such as '[Postma](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)n'.

Answer (score 0):

You might only have to add something like this:

```
var testName = 'Testing'; //Change Project's name here in order to be identified in BrowserStack




// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    seleniumAddress: 'http://xxxxx:xxxxx@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub',
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',//Local Appium
    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            name: testName,
            platformName: 'iOS',
            platformVersion: '7.1',
            browserName: '',
            app: 'safari',
            deviceName: 'iPhone Simulator',
            'appium-version': "1.4.0",
            username: 'xxxxxx',
            accessKey: 'xxxxx'

        }
        ,
        {
            name: testName,
            platformName: 'Android',
            platformVersion: '4.4',
            browserName: 'Browser',
            deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
            'appium-version': "1.4.0",
            username: 'xxxxx',
            accessKey: 'xxxxx'
        }


        ],
```

Answer (score -1):

You may run this little script:

```
browser.executeScript("sauce:job-name=" + name )
```

It's generally useful if you want to dynamically set the name during or right before the start of the tests.